# How to apply jquery mustache to external file/template

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, external, mustache

I am using this to 'get' my external html file, and then use mustache to append to that template's id:

```
 $.get('block.html', function(data) {
        $('#mydiv').append(data);
        
            var list = {
                       name : 'whatever'  
            };
                        
            $('#Block').mustache(list).appendTo('#mydiv');
    });
```

The file `block.html` would look like:

```
<script id="Block" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
My name is {{name}}
</script>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Because, at the moment, I am appending twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the jquery mustache plugin is great for when the template is inside your current document.

But here you have a different use case and the helpers provided by mustache itself are sufficient to do the job. So, just :

```
$.get('block.html', function(template) {
    var view = {name:'whatever'};
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
    // and now append the html anywhere you like
});
```

And in this case, your block.html can become:

```
My name is {{name}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library that I wrote, [Chevron](https://github.com/surdu/jquery-chevron), to load external templates from files like so:

You add in your HTML a link to your template file:

```
<link href="path/to/template.mustache" rel="template" id="templateName"/>
```

Then, in you JS you can render your template like so:

```
$("#templateName").Chevron("render", {name: "Slim Shady"}, function(result){
    // do something with 'result'
    // 'result' will contain the result of rendering the template
    // (in this case 'result' will contain: My name is Slim Shady)
});
```

The docs of Chevron will give more examples